# Using numpy select the index of a minimum value in an array excluding certain indexes

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy I am trying to extract the minimum distance to a city.

Distances is one row in the matrix e.g.

```
[50,33,66,55]
```

toVisit is one row minus visited indices e.g

```
visitedIndices = [0,3]  
toVisit = [33,66]
```

This line of code gets the index of the minimum value in toVisit.

```
city = np.where(distances == toVisit.min())[0][0]
```

The problem occurs if distances has a duplicate value for a distance as 2 indices will be returned by that line of code. I want to exclude the possibility of any indexes returning that we have previously visited.

I  could add something to check if the index has been visited afterwards aka:

```
city = np.where(distances == toVisit.min())[0]
for index in city:
    if index not in visited:
        city = index
```

But surely there must be a way to do this in the where clause?

Edit: If you run this:

```
distances = [20, 36, 55, 36]
visited = [0, 1]
toVisit = [55, 36]
city = np.where(distances == toVisit.min())[0]
```

city will be equal to two indexes 1 and 3 as we have previously visited index 1, I wish to exclude that index from appearing in the result of:

```
city = np.where(distances == toVisit.min())[0]
```

So city would be equal to just index 3

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and perhaps a better explanation of your problem, as it seems unclear to me

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
my_array = ...
mask = my_array > some_condition
argsort = np.argsort(my_array)
min_index_in_mask = np.min( argsort[mask))
```

The complexity is O(n log(n)) with `n` the size of `my_array`, because of `np.argsort`.